# TypeError, but not when inside React return function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am running into an issue where I get (TypeError: undefined is not an object) when I try to call an attribute of an object; however, this error does occur when it is called in a return function. Additionally, the error only happens when an attribute of an object is called, not the object itself.

I tried to keep the included code concise; although, I am not quite sure where the error is occuring, so there may be a bit of unnecessary information. Additionally, there are comments in the code notating where errors do and do not occur.

backend/models/course.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const courseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    fields: Array,
    number: Number,
    name: String,
    minCredits: Number,
    maxCredits: Number,
    description: String,
    isSaved: { type: Boolean, default: false },
});

const course = mongoose.model('courses', courseSchema);

export default course;
```

backend/controllers/course.js

```
import CourseData from '../models/course.js';

export const getSpecificCourse = async(req, res)=> {
    try {
        const selectedCourse = await CourseData.findOne({ _id: req.query.courseId });
        
        res.status(200).json(selectedCourse);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message});
    }
}
```

backend/routes/course.js

```
import express from 'express';
import { getSpecificCourse } from '../controllers/courses.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/courseId', getSpecificCourse);

export default router;
```

backend/server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import courseRoutes from './routes/courses.js';

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/courses', courseRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(mongoUrl, {dbName: "dbName"}) // Hidden for privacy
    .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () =>
        console.log(`Connection is established and running on port: ${PORT}`)
        )).catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

frontend/src/components/CoursePage.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios';
import './styles.css';

export function CoursePage() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [course, setCourse] = useState()
  const { courseId } = useParams()

  const url = 'http://localhost:5000/courses/courseId/?courseId=' + courseId;

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then( (selectedCourse) => {
        setCourse(selectedCourse.data);
        setLoading(false);
    } )
  }, [])

  console.log(course); // results in no error
  console.log(course.number); // results in an error (occurs when calling any attribute)

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
    
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(course)} // results in no error
      {console.log(course.number)} // results in no error (consistent with each attribute)
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the states isLoading is started as true and course is started as undefined:

```
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [course, setCourse] = useState()
```

And, then, your try to access course before it is defined:

```
// now the course is not defined yet.
console.log(course); // results in no error
console.log(course.number); // results in an error (occurs when calling any attribute)

if (isLoading) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>
}
```

If your change the code to:

```
if (isLoading) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>
}

console.log(course); // results in no error
console.log(course.number); // results in an error (occurs when calling any attribute)
```

Your code go works without any error, because the isLoading is setted to false only when the course state is set to the received object.